# rails validate uniqueness in parent scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got these models:

```
subdomain
company
tool
code
```

code belongs_to tool, tool to company and company to subdomain.
I want to validate the uniqueness of a code within a subdomain. How can I do that?
I know how to use scope to get uniqueness within tools scope like this:

```
validates :codevalue, :uniqueness => {:scope => :tools_id}
```

but how to do that for a scope two parents above?

I'm using the latest rails version.

Comment: I don't think `validates_uniqueness` can do this. Maybe you should write your own validation? (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations)

Comment: a custom validator would be ok, too. I know how to write and use them but I have no exact idea how to check the uniqueness in a more or less performant way..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it with a custom validation like this:

```
def validate_uniqueness_in_subdomain
  Barcode.where(:value => self.value).each do |code|
    next if code.eql?(self)
    if (self.tool.company.subdomain.id  == code.tool.company.subdomain.id)
      errors.add(:unique_error, "This barcode is already in use")
      break
    end
  end
end
```